# getting requested url from response

Tags: c, sockets

I am in need of figuring out the requested url from the http request but there seem to be none.

for example when i enter this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/heththethetkj909
```

the request does not contain the url

```
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.43 Safari/536.11
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

n-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

f-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"<doctype !html><html><head><title>Bye-bye baby bye-bye</title>"
"<style>body { background-color: #111 }"
"h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: white;"
" text-shadow: 0 0 2mm black}</style></head>"
"<body><h1>Goodbye, world!</h1></body></html>\r\n";

int main()
{
    int one = 1, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  char send_data [1024] , recv_data[2048]; 
      int  bytes_recieved ;  




    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
        err(1, "can't open socket");

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

    int port = 8080;
    svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
        close(sock);
        err(1, "Can't bind");
    }

    listen(sock, 5);
    while (1) {
        client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
        printf("got connection\n");

                bytes_recieved = recv(client_fd,recv_data,2048,0);
                printf(recv_data);

        if (client_fd == -1) {
            perror("Can't accept");
            continue;
        }

        write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
        close(client_fd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why?

In the first two lines of the HTTP request, we have

> GET **/favicon.ico** HTTP/1.1
>   Host: **127.0.0.1:8080**

this is correspondent to `127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico`.

What is favicon.ico? Did you notice that when you visit stackoverflow in a browser, there will be a stackoverflow icon on the left of address bar or on the left of page title in your tab bar. That's favicon. Browser will try to load that when you visit any web site, and use that as the picture. For details of favicon, see [wikipedia - favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

With the above said, this http request simply is not for `http://127.0.0.1:8080/heththethetkj909`. Therefore, you certainly won't see it. In this case, the first two lines of the HTTP request will read

> GET **/heththethetkj909** HTTP/1.1
>   Host: **127.0.0.1:8080**

The server is probably opening two connections simultaneously to your web server. One for `/heththethetkj909`, the other for `/favicon.ico`.  I'm actually not sure why you run into the problem as your original code seems to handle multiple connections. Maybe it's http persistence related issue.

## How to solve it?

Try adding 'Connection: close' in the header of your http response. It may help.

If you simply want to try a very basic implementation which doesn't handle this, consider trying a different browser which may have a different timing behavior of loading favicon, or a *very* old browser which doesn't know favicon, or something that's not a browser to hit your server, e.g. `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/heththethetkj909` in linux, or notepad in windows (yes, you can type a url in the open dialog of notepad).

Comment: could you please tell me how to make it answer two connections ?

Comment: @crowso, I'll get that in a few minutes.

Comment: i figured out to support 2 connections. You have to use a fork. Anyway your answer seemed to help me the most so i am accepting your answer.

Comment: @crowso I'm sorry. I was wrong and your original code should be able to handle multiple connections properly. Fork is not necessary if you simply want to handle multiple connections one after another. It is only necessary if you have to handle them simultaneously.

Comment: @crowso I've revised my answer to reflect this. Actually, I don't understand why your problem is solved after you use 'fork'.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser sends 2 HTTP requests:

1. For [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) - this is request you see. This is a small Icon you can see e.g. in chrome in  a page tab's corner.
2. Second request will be what you actually have typed.

I don't remember if both will be sent over the same connection or it will be 2 TCP connections.
You can check it with your favorite network sniffer (e.g. Wireshark - Windows/Linux, tcpdump - Linux).

Answer (score 0):

any change you're using the browser for testing ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

try using Curl when you're running tests.

something like:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/heththethetkj909
```

Comment: ok with curl i received the url. How can i make it appear with the browser?

Comment: well ... you could use strstr() to search and block the fabicon.ico request. This approach is very reliable since the browser only do this with fabicon.ico.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
```

indicates that the browser is trying to get the icon image for the site.  This is *not* the request that you're interested in.  You should also see a separate request that says

```
GET /heththethetkj909 HTTP/1.1
```